# Loop string get null

Tags: javascript, html

I want to output a loop string. this's my code:

**HTML**

```
<input id="items" type="text" value="">
<input id="start" type="text" value="">
<input id="end" type="text" value="">
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Generate">
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var items = document.getElementById('items').value;
var i = document.getElementById('start').value;
var e = document.getElementById('end').value;
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(i; i < e; i++) {
        output.value = items+'/'+i;
    }
}, false);
```

how to ouput like 'pencil/1' until 'pencil/20' by input value start and end? cause i get null value input to use for.

Comment: Its not clear what your actual problem is here. One thing I can see is that you are overwriting output.value on each step of the loop. I'm not sure where the null that you are getting is occurring though...

Comment: I think problem could be accessing `.value` properties before window load, put all your js in `window.onlaod`

Comment: Chris : what i want is to dump pencil/1,pencil/2,pencil/3 and so on.

Mritunjay : can you make example code? i put the script in below body.

Comment: @lynxpravoka: I got what you were tryign to do. I was just unclear on what the problem you were having was. I understand now and my answer should solve it (with proof of concept demo in a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the values of items, start and end on page load, not when you are clicking the button. Include those inside your click event and it will work better.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
var items = document.getElementById('items').value;
var i = document.getElementById('start').value;
var e = document.getElementById('end').value;
    for(i; i < e; i++) {
        output.value += items+'/'+i+'\n';
    }
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e1xsj4x2/ is a fiddle demonstrating this. It also correctly appends the values to the text area rather than overwriting the existing value on each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you Chris :) its a pleasure to meet you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var items = document.getElementById('items').value;
    var i = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var e = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    for(i; i<e; i++){
        output.value = output.value + items + '/' + i + '\n';
    }
}, false);
```

Add getting variables into click function, because they are undefined after load. This will output all items from-to.

Comment: my real problem is i get null value `i` and `e` from input element.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @lynxpravoka: That should really be edited into the question itself to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: Mulla azzi : Chrome Browser and Firefo.

Chris : i have updated it.

Comment: Is your comment on html errors still valid? The HTML looks fine to me so the question may have been updated since you posted that.

Comment: ok, i get it now. the var is not identified by if outside event.

Comment: no it is no longer valid, because someone updated original post